# Cannot see advertisement with admob ane

Tags: admob, ane

I followed https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash

I am still unable to see advertisements with admob ane.

**Steps**:

1.Init Admob ANE

Add Admob ane to air project build path, and add the following code in the script file

```
import so.cuo.platform.admob.*;
Admob.getInstance().initAdmobSDK("your admob app ID");
```

2.Add Admob Banner in adobe Air App

Here is the minimal code needed to show an admob banner.

```
Admob.getInstance().showBanner("your banner ID ",AdmobSize.BANNER_320x50,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

The AdmobPosition class specifies where to place the banner. AdmobSize specifies which size banner to show

3.Remove Banner
By default, banners are visible. To hide a banner,

```
Admob.getInstance().hideBanner();
```

4.Admob ANE Show Interstitial

Here is the minimal code to integrate an interstitial into an Air ios app or flex android app.

```
Admob.getInstance().cacheInterstitial("your Interstitial ID ");
```

Check that the interstitial is loaded before showing it:

```
if (Admob.getInstance().isInterstitialReady()) {
  Admob.getInstance().showInterstitial();
}
```

5.Custom Admob Banner Ad Sizes

In addition to constants on AdSize, you can also create a custom size:

```
//Create a 320x250 banner.
AdSize adSize = new AdSize(320, 250);
Admob.getInstance().showBannerAbsolute(adSize,0,30);
```

6.Set Admob Target Param

If you want advertisements to target children:

```
  extraParam=new ExtraParameter();
extraParam.testDeviceID="true";
extraParam.isChildApp=true;//if is tagForChildDirectedTreatment,set true
    extraParam.isDesignedForFamilies=true;
    extraParam.nonPersonalizedAds=true;//if want to load non Personalized ads set true
Admob.getInstance().showBanner("Your banner ID",AdmobSize.BANNER_320x50,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,80,extraParam);
```

7.Ad Events

Both Banner and Interstitial contain many ad events that you can register for.
To set ad events on an interstitial and show interstitial when the ad is successfully loaded:

```
 Admob.getInstance().addEventListener(AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive, onAdEvent);
    private function onAdEvent(event:AdmobEvent):void
    {
        if (event.type == AdmobEvent.onBannerReceive)
        {
            trace(event.instanceName,event.data.width, event.data.height);
        }
        if (event.type == AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive)
        {
            Admob.getInstance().showInterstitial();
        }
    }
```

8.Admob Rewarded Video

Video api is similar with Interstitial

To set an ad event on a video and show video when the ad is successfully loaded:

```
if(admob.isVideoReady()){
    admob.showVideo();
}else{
    admob.cacheVideo(videoID);
}
    Admob.getInstance().addEventListener(AdmobEvent.onVideoReceive, onVideoEvent);
    private function onVideoEvent(event:AdmobEvent):void
    {
        if (event.type == AdmobEvent.onVideoReceive)
        {
            trace("load video success,you can show video now");
        }

    }
```

9.IOS min version config

admob requires ios 8 and later

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
```

simple example

```
<iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
                <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
            <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
        ]]></InfoAdditions>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>
```

10.android permission config

Meta Config com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID is required from admob 17 Please replace ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 with your admob ID

```
<android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
                 <application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

                 </application>
            </manifest>
        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ANE is very old and outdated. AdMob SDK has changed several times since then with a major update in 2018. You can use [this one](https://github.com/tuarua/AdMob-ANE) which is almost always updated.